# connect server over net::ssh

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

hy 
i write this code in my script

```
def connect_sql
    Net::SSH.start( @host, @user, :port=>22, :verbose => :debug ) do |ssh|                                                                                   
    puts ssh.exec!("./root/scripts/MysqlCleanInstance.sh #{@uid}")
  end
```

end

The probleme is for etablish a conenction between two server we use dns .The DNS information are in /etc/resolv.conf.

i dont know why  when i try to connect to another server i get this error:

```
, [2014-01-08T17:55:34.905977 #28115] DEBUG -- tcpsocket[3f87c7e6b534]: received packet nr 5 type 51 len 44
D, [2014-01-08T17:55:34.906129 #28115] DEBUG --   net.ssh.authentication.session[3f87c7e5b2b0]: allowed methods: publickey,password
D, [2014-01-08T17:55:34.906309 #28115] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.methods.keyboard_interactive[3f87c7e58948]: keyboard-interactive   failed
E, [2014-01-08T17:55:34.906487 #28115] ERROR --  net.ssh.authentication.session[3f87c7e5b2b0]: all authorization methods failed (tried none, publickey, hostbased, password, keyboard-interactive)
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:215:in `start': Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed)
    from clean_instance.rb:87:in `connect_sql'
```

Comment: did you test the plain enter into remote host via ssh as: `ssh user@host`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your SSH keys are in place. It appears you are not able to authenticate over SSH, even after all authentication methods have been tried.

The reason you are unable to connect to another server is likely because you are not able to authenticate with that other server using a SSH key, which I assume you were able to do with the first server.